# Angular Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress on document.click()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, typescript

I often recive the " $apply already in progress" Error at this peace of code:

```
public addFile(): void {
    if (window["File"]) {
        $("#fileSelector").click();
    }
}
```

the addFile function is called by ng-click, has someone an idea how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

> ng-click, has someone an idea how to avoid it

This is probably happening because the element `"#fileSelector"` also has an `ng-click` attached to it. So *that* click will do a `scope.$apply` and therefore you will get this error.

However I suspect that you are actually calling `scope.$apply` *yourself*. You shouldn't do that if *that* code is going to be called from `ng-click` or another *well-behaved* angular directive.